# Query urls that have been liked by a user via the Facebook like button?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I want to offer the user a list of urls that he/she has clicked the like button on my site.

This is some sort of "favorite list". The user should have a benefit and also it should encourage liking pages.

There is the `edge.create` and `edge.remove` javascript callback event that fires when the like button is clicked and also passes the url. I can real-time write that into my database.

However this event is asynchronous, takes about a second and is thus not guarantee to go all the way through. So i want to offer the user a "synchronize" link on the page where the user gets the list of posts he/she liked on my page.

On the graph API there is the `https://graph.facebook.com/me/likes` connection. However this seems to only include "facebook pages" that have been liked. Not urls via the like button.

I have the `og` tags setup, so every liked page should be automatically added as a facebook page, but they are however not included in the response.

After some research I came across this query:

```
SELECT post_id, likes FROM stream WHERE source_id = me() and likes.user_likes = 1
```

which looks promising but the user_likes field is not indexed and thus cannot be put a filter on.

I also cannot do much with the FQL `like` table because I am not interested in the users that liked a special link.

I want to know the links that a user liked on my website.

Is it somehow possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/url_like/

You can try using the url_link table which can only be queried with the user_id. It will return to you, all the urls he/she liked. However you need to filter the returned list on your application for your own urls